# Converting user input to gibberish muppet talk

Tags: java, string, if-statement, replace, str-replace

I'm trying to translate English into the fake language of the Swedish chef. The language rules in priority order are as follows:

- Replace all occurrences of “AN” with “UN”.
- Replace all occurrences of “AU” with “OO”.
- Replace all occurrences of “A” not at the end of a word with “E”.
- Replace all occurrences of “OW” with “OO”.
- Replace all occurrences of “O” with “U”.
- Replace the first occurrence of “I” other than at the start of a word with “EE”.
- Replace all occurrences of “EN” at the end of a word with “EE”.
- Replace all occurrences of “E” at the end of a word with “E-A”.
- Replace all occurrences of “E” at the start of a word with “I”.
- Replace all occurrences of “U” with “OO”.

AUTHOR should be translated OOTHOR, but my code translates it to UUTHOR. This is because my code is following the 5th rule (the one for when there is an "OO").

So, how do I get the fifth parameter to apply only when it sees a single "O" and not an "OO"?

This is my code:

```
String entry;
String entry6;
String entry7;
String entry8;
String entry9;
String entry11;
String entry10;
String end;

System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE SWEDISH CHEF TRANSLATOR!");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a phrase in english: ");
entry = scan.next();

String entry1 = entry;
int length = entry1.length();
String entry4;

System.out.println("1: " + entry1);
// AN TO UN
String entry2 = entry.replace("AN", "UN");
System.out.println("2: " + entry2);

// AU TO OO
String entry3 = entry2.replace("AU", "OO");
System.out.println("3: " + entry3);

// A TO E
String lastL = entry3.substring(length - 1, length);
int index2 = lastL.indexOf("A");
if (index2 < 0) {
    entry4 = entry3.replace("A", "E");
} else {
    String beg = entry3.substring(0, length - 1);
    String replacedA = beg.replace("A", "E");
    System.out.print(replacedA);
    entry4 = lastL;
}
System.out.println("4: " + entry4);

// OW TO OO
String entry5 = entry4.replace("OW", "OO");
System.out.println("5: " + entry5);

// O TO U
entry6 = entry5.replace("O", "U");
System.out.println("6: " + entry6);

// I TO EE
String firstL = entry6.substring(0, 1);
int index3 = firstL.indexOf("I");
if (index3 < 0) {
    entry7 = entry6.replaceFirst("I", "EE");
} else {
    String endWord = entry6.substring(1, length);
    String replacedI = endWord.replaceFirst("I", "EE");
    entry7 = firstL + replacedI;
}
System.out.println("7: " + entry7);

// EN TO EE
length = entry7.length();
String En = entry7.substring(length - 2, length);
String substring2 = En.replace("EN", "EE");
entry8 = entry7.substring(0, length - 2) + substring2;
System.out.println("8: " + entry8);

// E to E-A
String lastL2 = entry8.substring(length - 1, length);
int index4 = lastL2.indexOf("E");
if (index4 < 0) {
    entry9 = entry8;
} else {
    String replacedE = lastL2.replace("E", "E-A");
    entry9 = entry8.substring(0, length - 1) + replacedE;
}
System.out.println("9: " + entry9);

// E TO I
String firstL2 = entry9.substring(0, 1);
length = entry9.length();
int index5 = firstL2.indexOf("E");

if (index5 < 0) {
    entry10 = entry9;
} else {
    end = entry9.substring(1, length);
    entry10 = "I" + end;
}
System.out.println("10:" + entry10);

// U to OO
entry11 = entry10.replace("U", "OO");
System.out.println("11:" + entry11);
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Du unsvers tu thees qooesshun need tu be encheferized? Bork bork bork! http://www.tuco.de/home/jschef.htm

Comment: Are you allowed to use hashmap data structure ? (probably not)

Comment: Shouldn't *everything* just be "bork, bork, bork?"

Comment: @MarsAtomic - what ???

Comment: Should all rules be applied to one word, or if one of them would already change word rest is skipped? I am asking because you claim that `AUTHOR` should be translated into `OOTHOR`, which means that only second rule `AU->OO` was applied here, but none of rest like fifth `O->U` which would change this word into `OOTHUR`.

Comment: ANGRY - How do you translate this ? UN-GRY or E-NGRY. Your rulese conflict with each other.

Comment: @Pshemo O --> U is a single O to U and my program is doing that for a double OO to UU, thus I'm trying to figure out how to get it only to change if it finds a single O, so if there is a double, nothing will happen

Answer (score 1):

Copy the converted parts of the string to a new string and keep incrementing the starting point of the original. 
Otherwise it will keep replacing the converted part of the string as well.

Simple Algorithm (not tested):

```
output = ""
x=0
for (i=0;i<input.length;i++) 
    holder = input.substring(x,i);
    if(holder.endswith(<iterate all replaceable patterns>))
        x = i;
        output += holder.substring(0, holder.length - pattern.length); //get non-replaceable part
        output += applyReplacement(detectedpattern);
output += holder //collect any remaining chars
```

Comment: could you clarify this a little more? sorry im a beginnner in compsci 2 class.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this using a different approach.

Use a `StringBuilder` or a `StringBuffer`.

```
StringBuilder target = new StringBuilder();
```

Keep an index inside the entry field, and flags that tell you whether you are at the beginning of a new word.

```
int curr = 0;
```

Now scan your entry, checking double letter combinations first. If they match (including word beginning/end rule), append the appropriate characters to the `target` variable, and add 2 to `curr`.

Next check single letters. If they match, append the appropriate character to `target`, and add 1 to curr.

If no match, append the current character (`entry.charAt(curr)`) to `target` and add 1 to curr.

When you reach the end of the string, convert `target` to String, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a copy of the text in another variable. Each time when you replace a character in the first text, you replace the corresponding character in the copy with `%`. Only replace a character in the first text if the corresponding character in the copy is not `%`. If you add this to your code, it will work without a hassle.